# How to set the Log_Level in Ada library alog

Tags: logging, ada

I am using the library [alog](https://www.codelabs.ch/alog/) for the first time in a project. I have a problem understanding how to set the log level for all subsequent log commands.

See my test program:

```
with Alog;                         use Alog;
with Alog.Logger;
with Alog.Policy_DB;               use Alog.Policy_DB;

procedure Test_Loglevel
is
   L : Logger.Instance (Init => True);

   procedure Act_And_Log
   is begin
      null;
      L.Log_Message (Alog.Debug, "very detailed, only for debugging");
      null;
      L.Log_Message (Alog.Info,  "some more detailed infos");
      null;
      L.Log_Message (Alog.Notice, "general messages for interactive use");
      null;
      L.Log_Message (Alog.Warning, "something serious happened");
      null;
      L.Log_Message (Alog.Error, "error messages should always be displayed");
   end Act_And_Log;

begin
   --
   -- all logs should be displayed
   --
   Set_Loglevel ("*", Debug);
   Set_Default_Loglevel (Debug);
   Act_And_Log;
   --
   -- only error
   --
   Set_Loglevel ("*", Error);
   Set_Default_Loglevel (Error);
   Act_And_Log;

end Test_Loglevel;
```

I would expect that all 5 messages are displayed the first time and only the error message is displayed the second time. The actual output, however, shows the 5 messages twice!

What do I have to do to filter the output based on severity?

Answer (score 0):

I directly asked the authors of alog. They responded with a [patch](https://git.codelabs.ch/?p=alog.git;a=commit;h=ee2ba06bee617ec896b52d53ad1f239105dcb5f1). I still find the doc a bit misleading.